# How does screen resolution effect design of a mobile web application?

Tags: mobile-website, resolution, screen-resolution, screen-size

I have been doing some research into creating a mobile web application, I have got to the design phase and as a bit of research I have compiled a list of the current generation of smart phones their screen size and also their resolutions.

So we all know that there are a tonne of mobile phones out there each with different screen sizes, but should I be looking at physical screen size or resolution when designing my mobile web application (or both)?

Cheers, 
IW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Both physical screen size and resolution are important when designing a mobile web site.**

Screen size is important because it will define how much content can be placed on the website and also define how big your hit areas can be (essential for touch input devices).

Resolution will determine the amount of detail you can have on your page, this affects things like graphics.

A few suggestions as to how you can make your website work well across a range of devices:

- Resize graphics to fit each device that your site is requested from. This will ensure that the presentation is consistent across most devices.
- Favor flexible sizes for elements on your page - use percentages as opposed to fixed dimensions and specify text sizes in relative sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is very important for laying out your UI components. An app designed for a larger screen may end up showing far too tiny fonts/control elements etc which may not be comfortably usable if you just blindly scale it down for a smaller display area.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if below would help but here is what i do;

I don't use images as ui elements but css and html elements
I don't define font sizes in pixels but as medium,small,large etc
For resizing banners or images I mainly use http://deviceatlas.com or http://wurfl.sourceforge.net. If I can't be bothered I simply create images that aren't wider than 240px

You could also look in to frameworks such as jQuery Mobile